# Assembly x86 what's the purpose of "enter 0,0"

Tags: assembly, visual-c++, x86, inline-assembly

At the moment I am learning assembly for x86 with NASM. I tried to write the following function who is calculating the fibonacci numbers:

```
unsigned int fibonacci(unsigned int n) {
    if (n < 2)
        return 1;
    else
        return fibonacci(n - 1) + fibonacci(n - 2);
}
```

This is what I did so far, and it works great, exactly like the above method. But as I understand the `enter 0,0` instruction is there to free up space in the stack for local variables. I push two local variables to the stack: `push dword ptr[n]`. But shouldn't this only be possible if I use the `enter` instruction like this: `enter 8,0`. To free up space for the two int variables. If I try to do so, I get a StackOverflow exception.

```
__declspec(naked) unsigned int fibonacci2(unsigned int n) {
    __asm {
        enter 0,0
        cmp dword ptr [n], 2
        jae elsee
        mov eax, 1
        jmp end
        elsee:
        push dword ptr[n] // Here I am pushing two local variables to the stack.
        push dword ptr[n] // 2 * 4 Bytes
        dec [ebp-4]
        dec [ebp-8]
        dec [ebp-8]
        push[ebp-4]
        call fibonacci2     
        mov [ebp-4], eax
        push [ebp-8]
        call fibonacci2
        add eax, [ebp-4]
        end:
        leave
        ret
    }
 }
```

This is the compiled version of the function:

```
00C426E0  enter       0,0  
00C426E4  cmp         dword ptr [n],2  
00C426E8  jae         fibonacci2+11h (0C426F1h)  
00C426EA  mov         eax,1  
00C426EF  jmp         end (0C42716h)  
elsee:
00C426F1  push        dword ptr [n]  
00C426F4  push        dword ptr [n]  
00C426F7  dec         byte ptr [ebp-4]  
00C426FA  dec         byte ptr [ebp-8]  
00C426FD  dec         byte ptr [ebp-8]  
00C42700  push        dword ptr [ebp-4]  
00C42703  call        _fibonacci2 (0C413BBh)  
00C42708  mov         dword ptr [ebp-4],eax  
00C4270B  push        dword ptr [ebp-8]  
00C4270E  call        _fibonacci2 (0C413BBh)  
00C42713  add         eax,dword ptr [ebp-4]  
end:
00C42716  leave  
00C42717  ret
```

Comment: `push` allocates space automatically. If you want to use the `enter 8,0` version you don't need to `push` because you already got the space allocated.

Comment: That "compiled" version still doesn't show the real addressing mode for `push        dword ptr [n]`.  If it's relative to ESP, then it breaks as soon as you use `enter`.  Also, notice that your DEC picked `byte ptr` operand-size when you wrote that ambiguous `dec [ebp-4]`  That's pretty horrible; a good assembler would error on that ambiguity instead of picking one arbitrarily.  Also, load into a register and do math there to store modified copies of `n`.  Memory-destination instructions cost store/reload store-forwarding latency for every access to the data.

Comment: And BTW, none of this is NASM syntax.  You're using MSVC which uses MASM syntax for its inline asm, with special definitions for `n` that makes it expand to something like `[ebp+8]`.

Comment: @PeterCordes : With `__declspec(naked)` there is no prologue and epilogue generated by the compiler, BUT all references to parameters are via _EBP_. If you create a function `__declspec(naked)` that has parameters and the inline assembly references them they are guaranteed to be done via _EBP_. What that means is if you create a naked function and the function has parameters and you reference them in inline assembly, the inline assembly has to at least `PUSH EBP` `MOV EBP, ESP `(or the equivalent with `enter` at the start in order for those references to be correct.

Comment: The two MSDN articles that apply to this are the one on the naked attribute (rules and limitations): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/rules-and-limitations-for-naked-functions?view=vs-2019 and the other is on writing function prologue and epilogue code: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/considerations-for-writing-prolog-epilog-code?view=vs-2019

Comment: @Jester Thanks, this was the misconception I had. Now everything makes sense. Thank you again. You saved my day!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> To free up space for the two int variables.

The compiler does not need to use the stack for local variables. In some cases it can even optimize stack usage away completely and store local variables in registers.

> I push two local variables to the stack: push dword ptr[n]. But shouldn't this only be possible if I use the enter instruction like this: enter 8,0.

The `enter` instruction does **exactly the opposite** of what you think it does:

It does **not allocate** (stack) memory that can be used by `push` instructions, but it **uses** (stack) memory the same way the `push` instruction does:

`enter 80,0` works like doing `enter 0,0` first and then performing `push` 10 times with 10 *random* values. This is useful to "create" 10 uninitialized local variables on the stack.

As already written `enter 0,0`, will only `push` and initialize the `ebp` register. Using a real C compiler with optimization enabled, you would probably not get an `enter` instruction in this case.

> If I try to do so, I get a StackOverflow exception.

Difficult to say why:

If you call your function for a large number, your function will require a lot of stack. By using `enter 8,0` instead of `enter 0,0` you require `8*n` bytes more stack for a function argument `n`.

If your stack is already nearly "full" when using `enter 0,0`, it will definitely be full when using `enter 8,0`.

Second thing is that your disassembly is not complete:

- Obviously, the C compiler added some wrapper named `_fibonacci2` (with an underscore) located at address `0C413BBh`.
- The disassembly does not show `n` as `ebp+8` but as `n`.

It might be that the error cannot be seen in the code that you have posted:

- It may be located in the wrapper at address `0C413BBh`
- Or `n` has not been replaced correctly (by `ebp+8`)

Comment: According to [@MichaelPetch's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56779327/assembly-x86-whats-the-purpose-of-enter-0-0/56784355#comment100117767_56779327), MSVC guarantees that `[n]` in a `naked` function expands to `[ebp +- constant]`.  (Your function is thus *required* to set up EBP as a frame pointer if you want to use C var names in the inline asm instead of managing the calling convention and ESP offsets yourself.)

Comment: @PeterCordes Sorry, I did not read that. However, I edited my answer anyway because I saw the two `push dword ptr [n]` instructions - so [esp+8] would not have been possible.

Comment: No worries.  I wondered the same thing in my comment.  But I thought it was probably EBP so I didn't post it as an answer.

Comment: Oh, well spotted that the `call` isn't going to the address of the `enter 0,0`.  That definitely looks suspicious.  And good explanation of the OP's confusion in the first half of the answer.

Comment: @PeterCordes The calls are going to an intermediate JMP Thunk table for hot patching code. This is clearly a debug build. Address 0C413BBh will contain the instruction `jmp 00C426E0`

Comment: @MichaelPetch: I wondered about that, but was assuming it wouldn't do that for a self-call inside a `naked` function because it seems pointless.  Oh well.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: yes, that's what I thought.  But it could bypass that indirection for recursive calls (in C or inline asm) because the call-site will always be recompiled along with the target.  But that's an optimization that's not necessary for correctness.

Comment: The problem with `enter 8,0` is that the `push`es will then write to `ebp-12` and `ebp-16`  and the referenced `ebp-4` and `ebp-8` will contain garbage.

Comment: @Jester Would you add this comment as "answer"?